# NSPredicate code crashing on NSMutableArray ? objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

this is my NSMutableArray format and this is working fine and am getting correct response also

```
[
    {
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":"completed",
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":"<null>" 
    },{
        "status":"completed",
        "rating":"<null>"
    },{
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":"<null>" 
    }
]
```

and code is

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed' and self.rating == NULL"];

NSArray *arr = [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but in some case my NSMutableArray may change to this form

```
[
    {
        "status":not completed,
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":not completed,
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":not completed,
        "rating":4 
    }
]
```

now my code is crashing here

```
NSArray *arr = [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

i have attached console screen here

crash

THERE WAS A MISTAKE IN CODE LIKE 
before it was `NSDictionary *jorder = response;`  to use predicate i converted this to `NSMutableArray *jorder = response;`

[image]

Crash saying

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13f209b60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1841e6db0 0x18384bf80 0x1841edc4c 0x1841eabec 0x1840e8c5c 0x1001354ac 0x100135278 0x1000aaf4c 0x1001549cc 0x100e55a7c 0x100e55a3c 0x100e5b4e4 0x18419cd50 0x18419abb8 0x1840c4c50 0x1859ac088 0x1893ae088 0x100125798 0x183c628b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: try this rating.length <= 0...instead of checking it with NULL.

Comment: use 'nil' instead of 'NULL' in comparison.

Comment: but crash may be due to there is no object with status "completed"

Comment: @balkaransingh ur answer also crashing like mine

Comment: @Bangalore it is working my side . your <null> is a string .

Comment: @Bangalore Have you check after removing `self.rating` condition from predicate?

Comment: @Nirav its not crashing when i remove rating

Comment: @Bangalore i know that that's why i want you to check that, the problem here is that your server return null object if rating is 0.

Comment: but there is no rating 0, minimum is 1

Comment: I am saying that it doesn't get any rating that why you are getting null value for that object.

Comment: how do i solve this?

Comment: @Bangalore   balkaransingh's code working fine ,please check this...

Comment: @Bangalore: just small change will work without crash          NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed' and self.rating = NULL"];

Comment: this was my previous crashing code @kaushal

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed' AND self.rating == %@",@"<null>"];

NSArray *arr = [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Result

[image]

in my debug its show result
[image]

Comment: @Bangalore there must be other reason of crash see my updated answer.

Comment: you are not checking my question , dude i have only these [
    {
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":2 
    },{
        "status":"not completed",
        "rating":4 
    }
]   i dont know how u r getting completed in this

Comment: @Bangalore i check from your both array wait i show other array  response.

Comment: @Bangalore Because balkaran added <null> as string and you getting nil object in your response from api.

Comment: @Nirav its ur code which is crashing from previous question

Comment: if you remove `self.rating` condition from the predicate it will work properly check it once.

Comment: @Bangalore see i use your array and get 0 result without crash.

Comment: i removed rating from my existing code then its not crashing at all

Comment: @Bangalore: just small change will work without crash          NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed' and self.rating = NULL"];  NULL is  C pointers (type void *).  and == checking for actual object pointer address.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15087ad70'

Comment: that means your are  filtereding NSCFDictionary it is not a array @Bangalore

Comment: Good So you finally found the issue @Bangalore :)

Comment: is there any way to use predicate on NSdictionary or Convert NSDictionary to NSMutableArray?

Comment: can you send me your id "response" value @Bangalore

Comment: {
    "completed_order_image_link" = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "2016-07-15T12:24:04.386+05:30";
    "customer_id" = 483;
    "customer_mobile" = 00000000;
    id = 4574;
    "o_fare" =     {
        
        "waiting_charge" = 0;
        "waiting_time" = 60;
        "waypoint_charge" = 0;
    };
    "previous_due" = 0;
    rating = "<null>";
    "receiver_mobile_number" = 00000000;
    "receiver_name" = Delta;
    status = completed;
    "tracking_url" = "<null>";
    "updated_at" = "2016-07-15T12:28:32.958+05:30";

}

Comment: @balkaransingh have you seen response (above)

Comment: @Bangalore yes i see plz wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117660/discussion-between-balkaran-singh-and-bangalore).

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
NSString *response=@"[{\"status\":\"not completed\",\"rating\":2},{\"status\":\"not completed\",\"rating\":2},{\"status\":\"not completed\",\"rating\":2},{\"status\":\"not completed\",\"rating\":2},{\"status\":\"not completed\",\"rating\":2}]";
    NSData *data=[response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableArray *array=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed' AND self.rating == %@",@"<null>"];

    NSArray *arr = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and array is

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7f880a5eda70>(
{
    rating = 2;
    status = "not completed";
},
{
    rating = 2;
    status = "not completed";
},
{
    rating = 2;
    status = "not completed";
},
{
    rating = 2;
    status = "not completed";
},
{
    rating = 2;
    status = "not completed";
}
)
```

it will be work fine